# OAuth2 consent setup for individual private application

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth, gcp-ai-platform-training

I'm trying to send prediction requests to the google cloud ai platform from an android application. In order to do this I seem to need OAuth2 verification. I do not want to use the 'External' option as it is not an external application and will only be used by yours truly, but I cannot use the 'Internal' application without a G Suite account.

Comment: Unless you have G Suite or Cloud Identity, you are an external user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Cloud Functions, please take a look at this [Blog Post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/empower-your-ai-platform-trained-serverless-endpoints-with-machine-learning-on-google-cloud-functions).
Basically you can call Cloud Functions directly and Cloud Functions take care of the authentication to AI Platform.

Also this may help:

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/how-to-serve-deep-learning-models-using-tensorflow-2-0-with-cloud-functions